# Why does Pillow invert the colors when drawing via ImageDraw?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to paste an image into another on that is 8 bits/pixel (`L` mode), but the colors get inverted. How to fix this? A sample code:

```
icon_bmp2 = Image.open("assets/test_penguin.png")
icon_bmp2 = icon_bmp2.convert("L")
im2 = Image.new('L', (650, 500), 0xFF) # this line cannot be changed
image_draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
image_draw2.bitmap((0, 0), icon_bmp2)
im2.save('test.png') # inverted
```

The test image is from here: https://github.com/GregDMeyer/IT8951/blob/master/test/integration/images/sleeping_penguin.png, I'm using Python 3.7 and Pillow 7.2.0

Comment: You're using the wrong `ImageDraw` function — [`bitmap()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.bitmap) draws a mask in the current fill color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`Image.paste()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) function instead of `ImageDraw.bitmap()` to paste the pixels of one image onto another. It's also simpler to use since there's no need to create an `ImageDraw` first in order to use it.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


icon_bmp2 = Image.open("sleeping_penguin.png")
icon_bmp2 = icon_bmp2.convert("L")

im2 = Image.new('L', (650, 500), 0xFF)  # This line cannot be changed.
im2.paste(icon_bmp2)
im2.save('test2.png')
```

Non-inverted result

[image]